# how to split an image into 4 quadrant with python

Tags: python, string, image

I want to ask about how to divide an image into 4 quadrant with python. I want to divide it into quadrant 0,1,2 and 3. Then for each quadrant I want to split it into 4 more quadrant. For example assuming I have an image that have been divided into 4 quadrant, then I split quadrant 0 into 4 more quadrant which is quadrant 00,01,02, and 03.

Same thing with quadrant 1 when divided into 4 more quadrant,it will be quadrant 10,11,12, and 13.

Then if I enter string "03" it will print "the string is in quadrant 0".

Another example if I enter string "12" it will print "the string is in quadrant 1".

I thought of making it prints "error" if I enter string that start with number 4 and above.
Below is my code.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("8Greyscale.png")
pixels = np.matrix(im.getdata()).reshape(im.size)

width,height = im.size

add = input("string: ")

def grey(add,pixels):
if add[0] == 0:
   grey(add[1: ],pixels[len(pixels)//2:, :len(pixels)//2]) == 0
print("the string is in quadrant 0")

elif add[0] == 1:
   grey(add[1: ],pixels[:len(pixels)//2, :len(pixels)//2]) == 1
print("the string is in quadrant 1")

elif add[0] == 2:
   grey(add[1: ],pixels[len(pixels)//2:, len(pixels)//2:]) == 2
print("the string is in quadrant 2")

elif add[0] == 3:
   grey(add[1: ],pixels[:len(pixels)//2, len(pixels)//2:]) == 3
print("the string is in quadrant 3")

else:
  grey(add,pixels) == 4
print("error")
return add,pixels
```

There is error says "invalid syntax" on

```
elif add[0] == 1:
```

I don't know what do I have to do about this error. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why can't you just do `print("The string is in quadrant", add[0])`? If all you're doing is printing the name of the quadrant, I don't see why you need PIL.

Comment: I thought PIL is use to open image file? from the image data i want to split it into 4 quadrant.
your suggestion of 

    print("The string is in quadrant",add[0])

which part should I put it?do i put it after 

    return add,pixels

? I am still new in Python. Thanks for your answer